# Is there any way not to get CPU-throttled in the background?

Tags: ios

I have a CPU task that needs to occur when the app is running in the background (either by way of fetch or silent notification). This task takes about 1s when running in the foreground but about 9s when running in the background. It's basically saving out ~100K textual entries to a database. Whether I use `FileHandle` operations or a Core Data sqlite solution, the performance profile is about the same (Core Data is a little slower surprisingly).

I don't really want to get into the specifics of the code. I've already profiled the hell out of it and in the foreground it's quite performant. But clearly when the app is running in the background it's being throttled by iOS to the tune of a 9x slowdown. This wouldn't be such a big issue except in response to a silent notification iOS only gives the app 30-40s to complete and this 9s task can put it over the limit. (The rest of it is waiting on subsystems that I have no control over.)

**So the question:**

Is there any way to tell iOS *Hi, yes, I'm in the background but I really need this chunk of code to run quickly and avoid your throttling* ? FWIW I'm already running in a `.userInitiated` qos dispatch queue:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
  // code to run faster goes here
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I am seeing this exact same behavior, 5 seconds foreground, 90 seconds background.  I am using background tasks to get around the 30 second limit, but would be nice to get this to execute faster when in background, but understand why.

Answer (score 3):

First, no. The throttling is on purpose, and you can't stop it. I'm curious if using a `.userInitiated` queue is actually improving performance much over a default queue when you're in the background. Even if that's true today, I wouldn't bet on that, and as a rule you shouldn't mark something user initiated that is clearly not user initiated. I wouldn't put it past Apple to run that queue *slower* when in the background.

Rather than asking to run more quickly, you should start by asking the OS for more time. You do that by calling `beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler:)` when you start processing data, and then call `endBackgroundTask(_:)` when you're done. This tells the OS that you're doing something that would be very helpful if you could complete, and the OS may give you several minutes. When you run out of whatever time it gives you, then it'll call your expirationHandler, and you can save off where you were at that point to resume work later.

When you run out of time, you're only going to get a few seconds to complete your expiration handler, so you may not be able to write a lot of data to disk at that point. If the data is coming from the network, then you address this by downloading the data first (using a `URLSessionDownloadTask`). These are very energy efficient, and your app won't even be launched until the data is finished downloading. Then you start reading and processing, and if you run out of time, you squirrel away where you were in user defaults so you can pick it up again when you launch next. When you're done, you delete the file.

Comment: This shall be the actual solution. Just another additional suggestion would be dividing the data by sampling it with some basic values beforehand - before the actual operation - and try sending them as chunks seperately so that you can track easier where you left last.